# Angular2: Directive loads, but does nothing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

**EDIT:** I found the problem.  You know what it turned out to be?  A chrome caching issue. Chrome cached something, and until I turned off caching while the debugger was open and explicitly refreshed my page, I was getting nowhere.  Once I refreshed, I started getting events caught.

**Original Post:**
I have a custom Angular directive that's supposed to act on a control on any of three events: `onload`, `onblur`, or `onfocus`.  It's applied to an `input` control, which may or may not be disabled.  I know that `onblur` and `onfocus` are useless on a disabled control, but I suppose there'd be no harm in listening for events that never appear.  On the other hand, an enabled control will fire off those events, so I need to be listening.  This directive is designed to be fairly generic, so it needs to handle both a disabled and an enabled `input` control.

The problem is, it does nothing.  At the very least, it doesn't appear to do anything.  The directive is instantiated -- I've verified that the constructor fires off, and I've verified that `elementRef` points to an input control -- but that's about it.  None of the listeners work.

**Usage:**

```
<input myDirective disabled id="someId" name="someName" [ngModel]="myValue" />
```

**Directive:**

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ selector: "[myDirective]" })
export class MyDirective {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
    onFocus(value: string) {
        console.log("MyDirective: Focus caught.");
    }

    @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
    onBlur(value: number) {
        console.log("MyDirective: Blur caught.");
    }

    @HostListener("load", ["$event.target.value"])
    onLoad() {
        console.log("MyDirective: Load caught.");
    }
}
```

When I run everything, it loads fine.  No issues with missing modules, missing components, etc.  No errors in the console.  As I mentioned earlier, even breaking into the code using the debugger verifies that the directive was instantiated.  But I get no console output, either.  I would at least expect it for the `onload` event.  Do disabled `input` controls not fire those or something?

Comment: Where do you provide this directive and where do you use it(relation between the components)?

Comment: You should use @HostBinding('value') instead of methods with parameters.

Comment: @Fals: I'm not sure how that would help.  This is a simplified version -- really, it's just a test to see if I can even catch the events, which I can't.  I've tried changing `load` to `value` and `change`, and I've tried this on a non-disabled Input control.  Absolutely nothing fires -- not `blur`, not `focus`, not `value/change/load`; nothing.  I even tried handling `onInit` and just outputting the ID of the control and got zip.  "id=undefined".

Answer (score 1):

`onLoad` will not work because it is a window event and not a **form event**

Following are the list of events that can be handled for Form Elements

```
onblur  
onchange
oncontextmenu   
onfocus 
oninput 
oninvalid   
onreset 
onsearch
onselect
onsubmit
```

You have refer to it from this [**documentation**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)
Update based on comment

As you expected a MDN link to support the above answer **[here it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)**

[image]

**Resource events refers to the resources in the internet such as a web url.**

Comment: In general w3schools is not the very best place to learn. There were a lot of things that were not exactly/correctly explained. MDN is a far better place to link to.

Comment: So if onLoad won't work, and there doesn't appear to be an equivalent form event, is there an event I can use that fires when a control is displayed?  My shortened version aside, I'm trying to format a value in an input box when it loads, but I would need to know when it actually loads, wouldn't I?  Or can I use OnInit on the Directive and just set elementRef.target.value to the formatted value there?

Comment: when you want that to happen? during the component load put the method in the component and handle it